# refresh whole page after clicking/submitting into an iframe

Tags: html, css, redirect, iframe, refresh

So,

```
<?if($USERS_ON$)?><?if($USER_LOGGED_IN$)?>
<iframe width="920px" height="500px" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;" src="http://thc-cup.ucoz.com/content/uID-already.htm" onclick="refreshIframe();"></iframe>
<?endif?><?endif?><?if($USERS_ON$)?><?if($USER_LOGGED_IN$)?><?else?>
<iframe width="920px" height="500px" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;" src="http://login.uid.me/?site=dinterncup-thc&ref=http://interncup-thc.ucoz.com/" onclick="refreshIframe();"></iframe>
<?endif?><?endif?>
```

I would like that **AFTER** refreshing the page inside the iframe, to **refresh** OR **redirect** the **WHOLE** page. How can i do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function iframe1_onload(ctrl) {

OnExecute(button1)

}
```

then do

```
function button1_onclick {

}
```